# I want to display a list of hyperlinked items in Android.

Tags: android, listview

Some items in the list, if clicked, will hyperlink to a URL.
If there is no URL for the associated item, then clicking it should do nothing.

Should I use a ListView, or is there something better?

Comment: You can simply use textview to do the same...if its a valid URL it will jump to that particular url

Comment: Regular textView with `android:autoLink="all"` property will pick up on all links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can make a `Listview` layout with single textview
2. Use `Arraylist` to hold basically 2 things 
   i. The title of your Hyperlink
   ii. The Url it would redirect to
3. Set a `Adapter` to your `ListView`
4. Set a `ClickListener` to your `ListView`
5. When a Particular item is clicked you can the postion of your listView item to get content in a Arraylist

eg.

```
  arraylist.get(postion).name
  arraylist.get(postion).url
```

Now you can just start a WebView using Intents

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Also if you have too many items to be displayed, I would recommend using `RecyclerView`

Comment: I actually have an ArrayList containing instances of objects from a custom class.  Think of it as "cars".  I have many car objects, and a car object has a "name" and "URL" property.   I have added many cars to a CarsList array.  I want to populate the ListView using each car objects "name", and hyperlink to the URL property.   Can this work?

Comment: Yes it can work, when you populate your listView with Arraylist "cars" you can access both its name and url property. so lets say you clicked on 8th item...that means 8th item of the arraylist, so if you access the 8th item in arraylist using arraylist.get(). you get access to both its name and URL property.

Comment: Can you give me some guideline about how to populate a ListView that is in another class?    I have MainActivity, which loads up my ArrayList of cars.  But, the results are on a 2nd layout, called ResultsActivity.   I know how to display the ResultsActivity by using startActivity(Intent), but how can I manipulate the ListView in the ResultsActivity from within the MainActivity?

Comment: If im getting your question right, you want to populate your listView which is in other class with an ArrayAdapter from your MainActivity? So you basically want to send your ArrayList from MainActivity to your ResultsAcitivity and then populate your listview there? is that right?

Comment: Yes.  MainActivity is the initial screen.  The button_click() loads up this data/objects.   Now, I need to populate the ListView that is on the next screen.    I invoke ResultsActivity from MainActivity by using:  startActivity(intent);   But, before I do this, I need to populate the ListView somehow.The thread of execution is still running the onClick() of the button in the MainActivity.  Notice how the startActivity never actually deals with an instance of ResultsActivity.   Just the .class handle.

Comment: Never mind.  I just moved the ListView to the same class.  There is no reason to even have a ResultsActivity.  I will display ListView on MainActivity.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html), so in each result item view containing a [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) with attribute `android:autoLink="web"`, take a look in `android:linksClickable` attribute as well.